# dataset shift and adjustment in glmnet

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, fixed-effects-model, glmnet, stratification

I have two sets of data A and F; In each datasets, I have two types of data point, say, 0 and 1 and the goal is to make a classifier.

One strategy is training/fitting the model, using one dataset, and testing on the other. However, as you can see, there is a shift in the data.

to fit, one can use glment

```
fit = cv.glmnet(y~., data = ndata, family = "binomial", parallel = T, type.measure = "class", nfolds = 10)
```

The other strategy, would be pulling these data together, but also adjusting with respect to where they come from. (sort of stratification of data points according to their cohorts). (If I am not mistaken, it can be called fixed effect).

I wonder if I can set these set of data have different intercept ? or any other remedy ?

where the *cohorx*, is a factor in my *ndata* indicate if a datapoint comes from cohort A or F.

**Questions**
1) Will adding this fixed effect (cohorx), sort of enforce this adjustment ?
2) Are there any other treatment I can take try out ?

[image]

Comment: I'm curious why this question is tagged as 'random-effects-model'?

Comment: It would probably help you determine whether or not the shift actually matters by colouring the points by 0 or 1 as well. And the answer to 1) is yes.

Comment: @Randel I meant fixed effect. I will fix it now.

Comment: @user4581 then make sense :)

Comment: @Sheep the data is multi-dimensional (p=300), and the decision boundary is not that obvious within PCA ! (a salad-looking like!)

Comment: This is supervised learning right? What I mean is, in the graph you provided, you coloured the points by A and F. What if you further coloured it by A - 0, A - 1, F - 0, F - 1? I'm trying to see whether or not the shift in data actually affects your decision boundary. Also it might be worthwhile to investigate the reason for the shift rather than just attribute it to the datasets.

Comment: @Sheep It is a high-dimensional (p>300) and decision boundary are not so clear in the PCA plot. In fact, the plot I am showing, is a subset of original data ... and I chose this one, because the shift is clear... but let's not stick to this specific example (whether it is going to bring any benefit or no ...)